# Add Order in Admin Panel Broadleaf 6

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I know that before version 5, there was an Order in the Customer Care panel, and that they hide it intentionally. I saw this thread http://forum.broadleafcommerce.org/viewtopic.php?t=25329 
but when I try to add that row in the database, I get an error that that MODULE_ID value(4000) doesn't exist in the BLC_ADMIN_MODULE table. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The `module_id` column needs to match an entry in the `blc_admin_module` table. I think the `4000` value is no longer a valid entry from `blc_admin_module`.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add records to database.
To enable order or other entity managements to Broadleaf demo site you can use below sql script.
Here my sql, it run on DBeaver, if your db-client have errors you can manually change params:

```
@set SECTION_ID = 80 --check in db to get unique id
@set SECTION_MENU_TITLE = 'Taho Order'
@set SECTION_KEY = 'TahoOrderSection'
@set SECTION_DISPLAY_ORDER = 1

@set MODULE_ID = 80 --check in db to get unique id
@set MODULE_NAME = 'Taho Order Module'
@set MODULE_KEY = 'taho-order-module'
@set MODULE_ICON = 'blc-icon-globe'
@set MODULE_DISPLAY_ORDER = 800

@set PERMISSION_ID = 80 --check in db to get unique id
@set PERMISSION_TYPE = 'ALL'
@set PERMISSION_NAME = 'PERMISSION_ALL_ORDER_CLASS'
@set PERMISSION_KEY = 'PERMISSION_ALL_ORDER_CLASS'
@set ROUTE_PATH = '/taho-order'
@set ENTITY = 'org.broadleafcommerce.core.order.domain.Order'
@set IS_FRIENDLY = false

@set ENTITY_PERMISSION_ID = 80 --check in db to get unique id
@set CHILD_PERMISSION_ID = 80 --check in db to get unique id

--create new module for admin
insert into public.blc_admin_module
(ADMIN_MODULE_ID, "name", MODULE_KEY, ICON, DISPLAY_ORDER)
values
(${MODULE_ID}, ${MODULE_NAME}, ${MODULE_KEY}, ${MODULE_ICON}, ${MODULE_DISPLAY_ORDER});

-- Create Admin permissions and entity permissions for your new entity
insert into public.blc_admin_permission 
(ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID, DESCRIPTION, "name", PERMISSION_TYPE, IS_FRIENDLY)
values 
(${PERMISSION_ID}, ${PERMISSION_NAME}, ${PERMISSION_KEY}, ${PERMISSION_TYPE}, ${IS_FRIENDLY});

insert into public.blc_admin_permission_entity
(ADMIN_PERMISSION_ENTITY_ID, CEILING_ENTITY, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID)
values
(${ENTITY_PERMISSION_ID}, ${ENTITY}, ${PERMISSION_ID});

-- Add Role Permission XREF to the Permission
INSERT INTO public.BLC_ADMIN_PERMISSION_XREF 
(ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID, CHILD_PERMISSION_ID) 
VALUES 
(${PERMISSION_ID}, ${CHILD_PERMISSION_ID});

INSERT INTO public.BLC_ADMIN_ROLE_PERMISSION_XREF 
(ADMIN_ROLE_ID, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) 
VALUES 
(-1,${PERMISSION_ID});

-- Mapping sections and permissions
INSERT INTO public.BLC_ADMIN_SECTION 
(ADMIN_SECTION_ID, DISPLAY_ORDER, ADMIN_MODULE_ID, "name", SECTION_KEY, URL, CEILING_ENTITY) 
VALUES 
(${SECTION_ID}, ${SECTION_DISPLAY_ORDER}, ${MODULE_ID}, 
${SECTION_MENU_TITLE}, ${SECTION_KEY}, ${ROUTE_PATH}, ${ENTITY});

INSERT INTO public.BLC_ADMIN_SEC_PERM_XREF 
(ADMIN_SECTION_ID, ADMIN_PERMISSION_ID) 
VALUES 
(${SECTION_ID}, ${PERMISSION_ID});
```